# Azure function app v1 with KeyVault. Getting Azure.core not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

This has been driving me nuts for the past few days.

I'm trying to write an Azure Function App V1 that integrates with Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
Because Dynamics uses System.Web.Services I can't use any higher version of function app above v1.

I've tried to create a simple project that currently has Azure.Identity (1.5.0) with Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets (4.2.0) but every time I try to run this it blows up with...

**Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'**

I can see that Azure.Security.KetVault.Secrets has the requirment Azure.Core >= 1.15.0 and Azure.Identity is 1.20.0.

This is a new project with the following settings...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
     <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.5.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.38" />   </ItemGroup>   ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
     <None Update="host.json">
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </None>
     <None Update="local.settings.json">
       <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
       <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
     </None>   
</ItemGroup>
 </Project>
```

And in the code all I'm doing is the following....

```
 string keyVaultName = "**************";
 var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

 var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

From the above it should work?

What I'm doing, is it possible with V1 function apps?

Comment: <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>

Add this code to your Project settings > Build and Check

Comment: Same issue here. Colin, have you found a solution? @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Adding `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutput` to .csproj file didn't work for me. I'm using exactly the same package versions as Colin but Target Framework `net48`

Comment: Could you please try with this framework version 4.7.2 with VS 2019! It actually working for me without any errors in 4.7.2 with VS 2019 and but with 4.8, I'm getting errors only sometimes. I'm trying to figure it out. ***Try with 4.7.2 with VS 2019!***

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT same error with `net472` (Colin also uses net472 and gets this error). Can you provide a list of the package versions you're using?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EATPRW5.png - this is the packages I'm using in my project

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT There is no reference to Azure.Identity or Azure.Security.KeyVault.xy??

Comment: I created a new project exactly with the package versions from your screenshot and still getting the errror... You can find the project on github: https://github.com/VILLAN3LL3/MissingAzureCoreDemo/tree/master

Comment: Hi, I've just cloned the git repo from @MatterOfFact and am able to run the function on my local no problem! Are you having issues doing this or deploying? Am i missing something

Comment: incase I'm not missing something, maybe try a nuget restore in your solution?

Comment: According to [Supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#supported-versions) only .NET Framework 4.8 is supported for Functions 1.x

Comment: @classicSchmosby98 Thanks for testing the repository. Did you call the function or did you only run the solution? It is not a build error but a runtime error.

Comment: Ignore what I said - the Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys packages have dependencies listed in .NetStandard 2.0, and dotnet framework is not listed like it is for other nuget packages.... are you sure this should work? Or do you need to use older alternatives to talk to keyvault?